# How to update Spring Boot version using a command line

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, version

How do you update the spring boot version of a java application (preferably using a command line)? I have tried googling but I haven't found anything that works - these usually involve changing certain lines of code which I don't have in my pre-existing project.

EDIT: I have a build.gradle file with a line under dependencies that goes: classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.4.RELEASE") but when I change it to 2.3.0 it doesn't build correctly - I get an error saying "error: package javax.validation.constraints does not exist
import javax.validation.constrants.NotEmpty;"

Comment: Have you searched for `org.springframework.boot` in your `pom.xml` file in your project?

Comment: I don't have a pom.xml file - I just have a build.gradle file with a line under dependencies that goes: classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.4.RELEASE") but when I change it to 2.3.0 it doesn't build correctly

Comment: If you're not using Maven or similar tools, then you're probably the spring-boot `.jar` file. In that case, you need to manually download the new version and replace the old one in the project. If you don't want to do this in the future, you can use Maven, which makes it easy to manage libraries.

Comment: 2.1.4 to 2.3.0 is not a minor update, there could be Spring Boot changes that will require application changes

Comment: Instead of blindly updating versions, before doing so I suggest a read of the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to upgrade Spring Boot version automatically. You need to review your application source code and apply the update manually. How to do it will depend on you application e.g. if you are using Maven build tool then you should start by modifying `pom.xml`